# How can i print JSON.stringify into div or table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

how can i print JSON.stringify into div or table ?? or in custom section by id ??

this my cod :

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'server.php',
        dataType:"json",
        success : function (data) { 
            $("#orders").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    }); 
});
```

php

```
<?php 
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Contact', 'root', '');
    $statement=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myfeilds");
    $statement->execute();
    $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json=json_encode($results);
    echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: you should build the table yourself in the success callback with elements in data

Comment: Do you already have the HTML?Also since you get a json no need for stringify

Comment: So what i do for select all

Comment: No i need print all data with js - not php --- sorry my english is weak

Comment: So what i do for get all and show ? Please write to answer

Comment: @Toprex add a sample `data` in OP and i will try to create a demo for you

Answer (score 0):

you can use Angular / Kendo  / knockout or any of this framework for resolve this.
following example explain how to resolve this using kendo ui
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview

```js
function getAjax(){
   // in here put your ajax call. in this time i hardcode some values
   var val = [];
   val.push({id:'1',name:'google'});
   val.push({id:'2',name:'yahoo'});
   val.push({id:'3',name:'fb'});
  return val;
}

$(()=>{
     
      var val = getAjax();
        //Get the external template definition using a jQuery selector
        var template = kendo.template($("#javascriptTemplate").html());

        //Create some dummy data
       

        var data = template(val); //Execute the template
        $("#input").html(data); //Append the result
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.1.118/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<div id='input'>  </div> 

<script id="javascriptTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
        <table>
        # for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { #
            <tr> 
            <td> #=  data[i].id #</td> 
            <td>#=  data[i].name # </td>
            </tr>
 
        # } #
        </table>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not HTML:

```
$("#orders").html(JSON.stringify(data));
```

I guess you want:

```
$("#orders").text(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Of course, it's not going to look nice because JSON is designed for computers, not people.

Comment: So what can I use instead of the ...   I would  An easy way get the array Or in any other manner that could Inside the function return json print div + varible

Comment: @Toprex I presume English is not your mother tongue (neither it's mine) but I can't understand a word of your comment. Use instead of what? Get what array? How exactly can I improve my answer?

Comment: Sorry Sorry ! My English is very weak.I want to send select all database processing result with json   And I get it ...Such as code written in question ...But you said to me this is not the right way to do it..I'm looking this way three days But because my English is poor ...did not get the right answer ...If it's possible .You edit my cod javascript ... And write it correctly...In a way that could .I print data with JavaScript And I can pour into the div and give it style css ... Thanks